# Static IP set up to persist dns nameservers for Angstrom Linux on a beagle bone

Tags: linux, static, dns, ip

I am having an issue with persisting my nameserver and domain on my beaglebone that is running an angstrom version of linux.  I have tried editing my /etc/resolv.conf file to contain:

```
domain xx.xx.xx.xx
nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx
```

When I reboot, this file is overwritten somehow and is blank.   I have also tried putting in the /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address xx.xx.xx.xx
  netmask xx.xx.xx.xx
  gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
  dns-nameservers xx.xx.xx.xx
```

This also didn't work for me when after reboot.  Why is resolv.conf being overwritten? What can I do to persist these values so that when my device reboots, it will use the new values I entered?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, there are several fixes.
Long story short: Connman manages your network, and overwrites the /etc/resolv.conf when you reboot.

Possible fixes: Use connman to set nameservers

Easy fix: add nameserver to resolv.conf and prevent resolv.conf from being modified  `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` (using root)

Answer (score 1):

While the title of this thread mentions Angstrom, the issue also applies to debian.  The core issue actually has to do with Connection Manager managing IP stuff.  If you type:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

and see:

> # Generated by Connection Manager

to make it easy on yourself, use connection manager [facepalm].  Using super user:

```
su
connmanctl services
```

You will see a couple services listed.  Look for the one that is similar to:

> ethernet_04a316afa8e2_cable

Still using super user, type (replacing the hex # between "ethernet_" and "_cable" with your specific hex string:

```
connmanctl config ethernet_04a316afa8e2_cable --nameservers 8.8.8.8
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```